# USB HSF+ external drive partition won't mount. "(NO WRITE)" & "Resource busy" errors when trying fsck

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, repair, fsck

I was copying a huge file from a USB external drive when it suddenly disappeared from the Finder. I disconnected and connected it back, but the primary partition wouldn't mount. Rebooting the Mac didn't help.

If in the terminal I type

```
diskutil list
```

the primary partition disk4s2 does show up.

It does not show up, however, when I type in

```
df
```

because the partition is indeed not mounted.

I'm now trying

```
sudo fsck_hfs -fy /dev/disk4s2
```

in and the result is

```
** /dev/rdisk4s2 (NO WRITE)
Can't open /dev/rdisk4s2: Resource busy
```

I've already tried

```
diskutil unmountDisk force /dev/disk4s2
```

and fsck still won't run.

Full disk access is granted to the terminal in security system preferences.

I'm running macOS Ventura on an M1 Max and the drive is an USB external 8TB "WD My Book 25EE Media" formatted to Mac OS Extended (Journaled) i.e. HSF+.

Any ideas on how to make it mount?

Comment: Fix what? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen the main partition won't mount

Comment: Try check SMART, maybe it's *drive* rather than *file system* related. For all we know the drive itself reports busy.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen SMART is Incompatible / not supported

Comment: what kind of drive is this then?

Comment: it's a USB external drive, an 8TB "WD My Book 25EE Media" which ironically was recommended to me as reliable

Comment: What is it formatted as? MBR/GUID? HFS+/APFS? …or did you just leave it as shipped, which would probably be MBR/ExFAT… a bad choice for any OS. [I'm aware you're calling fsck_hfs but just to double-check]

Comment: I formatted it to Mac OS Extended (Journaled), so yeah, HFS+

Comment: It should support SMART, if it's somehow having problem with showing SMART data the drive may be faulty in the first place.

Comment: I don´t know what makes a drive SMART compatible or not, but I have a similar drive, working perfectly, and Disk Utility also states that it's not SMART compatible